# Can't get right query result that I need

Tags: c#, recursion, linq

I have an object

```
class item { Guid id; String name; List<item> childs;}
```

There is two portion of its data.

**cafe**

--John

----Box

--Romeo

and

**cafe**

--John

--Romeo

----Box

So, box just changed its owner.

Now I need to get this structure as a String.

So, it must be:

cafe,John,Box,Romeo

and

cafe,John,Romeo,Box

I have code:

```
public static IEnumerable<item> get_in_one_row(this IEnumerable<item> itemsTree)
    {
        return itemsTree.Select(p=>p).Union(itemsTree.SelectMany(p=>p.childs.get_in_one_row()));
    }
```

But I always get: cafe,John,Romeo,Box - no matter, who is owner of the box.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Union is not guaranteed to preserve order. It does a distinct operation. Use Concat.

Comment: There is something else wrong because for different inputs you should see at least different output. Might be wrong, but why is nothing changing. I thing you are misinterpreting something, or the input is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results in that order you need to traverse the tree in a different way:

```
public static IEnumerable<item> get_in_one_row(this IEnumerable<item> itemsTree)
    {
        return itemsTree.SelectMany(p => Enumerable.Repeat(p,1).Concat(p.childs.get_in_one_row()));
    }
```